# wrapping c++ library using Jni

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I want to make a wrapper that wrapping c++ library using Jni. Basically, I have 3rd party library which can read points(x,y,z) out of file. so, file path must be a input parameter.
my jni are something like 
`JNIEXPORT void JNICALL to_the_path_loadFile( JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,jstring filePath)`

`JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL to_the_path_getX( JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint index)`

The first method will load file, the second will get coordinate x.

Since the file has large amount of points, I can't load them all to memory.
My idea is using iterator to iterate each point and wrap it to Java object. That means I have to call `getX()` many times.

My question is how to avoid load file stream so many times? I am new to c++, is there a way that I can reference back to c++ object so i am able to tell which point i am reading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to Turix's solution but without the C++ global variable. Have `loadFile()` return a file descriptor and pass this to `getX()`. You should also have a `closeFile()` method to close the opened file after all of the X values are retrieved.

Since you have a lot a values you can also pass `getX()` a native array of doubles so it can retrieve many values in a single call. This is a different design but it would be much more efficient.

Also, consider using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Java) to create your wrapper classes. It makes creating and managing the Java side *much* easier.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a few ways to do that, but probably the easiest is to keep a global variable for the file in the C++ code that is initialized by your `loadFile()` call and referenced by your `getX()` calls.